# R Loop over triple nested list

Tags: r, list, loops, dataframe, nested

I have got a triple nested list in R. The structure is like my testlist down below:

```
df_yes = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:130,30,rep=TRUE)))
df_no = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:130,20,rep=TRUE)))

s1 = list(df_yes, df_no)
names(s1) = c("yes", "no")

df_yes = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:130,25,rep=TRUE)))
df_no = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:130,15,rep=TRUE)))

s2 = list(df_yes, df_no)
names(s2) = c("yes", "no")

DJF = list(s1, s2)
names(DJF) = c("s1", "s2")

df_yes = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:130,60,rep=TRUE)))
df_no = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:130,10,rep=TRUE)))

s1 = list(df_yes, df_no)
names(s1) = c("yes", "no")


df_yes = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:530,25,rep=TRUE)))
df_no = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:230,15,rep=TRUE)))

s2 = list(df_yes, df_no)
names(s2) = c("yes", "no")

JJA = list(s1, s2)
names(JJA) = c("s1", "s2")

total_list = list(DJF, JJA)
names(total_list) = c("DJF", "JJA")
```

I want to add now $x3 and $x4 in the yes and no dataframes. The content should be the first number of x1 for x3) and the first number of x2 for x4.

I know how to do that with a single dataframe or a simple nested list:

```
df1 = total_list$DJF$s1$yes

df1$x3 = substr(df1$X1, 1,1)
df1$x4 = substr(df1$X2, 1,1)
```

Or with a loop in a normal list:

```
for(i in 1:length(df)){
  df[[i]]$v3 = substr(df[[i]][,1], 1,1)}
```

But how can I access a triple nested list with a loop? Do I have to make a double loop with 2 variables, like [[i]][[k]][[1]]?

Answer (score 1):

this will not the most suitable solution,hope this will work

```
N <- names(total_list)
for (i in 1:length(N)) {

  name1 <- N[i]
  product1 = total_list[[name1]]
  K <- names(product1)

  for (n in 1:length(K)) {

    name2 <- K[n] 
    product2 = product1[[n]]
    dfnames = names(product2)

    for (l in dfnames) {

      df_t = product2[[l]]
      df_t$x3 = substr(df_t$X1, 1,1)
      df_t$x4 = substr(df_t$X2, 1,1)
      df_t$x3 <- as.numeric(df_t$x3)
      df_t$x4 <- as.numeric(df_t$x4)
      total_list[[name1]][[name2]][[l]] <- df_t
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! With this I got the solution now. The key is really to make a triple loop. Thank you!